# Codeigniter Session Lost When Using CURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, curl, codeigniter-3

I am trying to get CI session from an external file. I have a page on CI that dumps the current session. When i access direct it operates as expected. However when i access via CURL it returns nothing. I believe CI session is lost when sending request using CURL.

My question is how do i send this session data together with my curl request.
The code i am using is as below.

```
    $url        = "http://localhost/cdmcl/dashboard/getsession";
    $ch         = curl_init();
    $timeout    = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $data;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE so that cURL saves its cookies into a file. 
So, for Code Igniter you have to write like this:

> $this->curl->option(CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,'cookies_1.txt');

Comment: how can i implement that without using CI curl library. The library isnt available in CI 3

Comment: The curl library is not contained in the default library - you will need to install the curl extension for code-igniter.  Link : https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-curl

Comment: @jmsiox Be aware of 3 years old code. Check if something need to be changed to fit CI3 version.